# Why does my Choko keep dying off, but then it grows up from the ground again?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, fruits, vines

A Choko is vine which is supposed to thrive all year round but mine's dying off every winter. It grows in a subtropical area, but the weather is very changeable, sometimes it's as hot as summer other times it's cold winter weather.

The other thing is it's supposed to flower and fruit in Autumn and Winter but it dies off before it gets the chance to.

Could it be a pest or a disease? Or could it being over watered or over feeding it? I've given it mushroom mulch 2-3 times a year. Or maybe it's a male vine?

If anyone know why it's dying let me know.

Comment: More tags I can't use is "choko" and "not-fruiting"

Comment: What part of the world are you in or, if you're in America, what's your USDA zone?

Comment: Have you followed planting instructions similar to those in this article? https://homeguides.sfgate.com/grow-vines-chokos-70852.html

Comment: @Bamboo Victoria, Australia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite normal for your Choko vine to die back in winter - it's a perennial plant that grows, flowers, fruits and dies back down when the weather gets cold. Given the variable climate where you live (seems rather like the UK for that!) it might, in some years, be low temperatures during autumn causing a problem, but it doesn't seem that you always have cold temperatures at that time of year. This plant should flower during  March or April in the southern hemisphere, with fruits starting to form shortly afterwards. You don't mention even seeing any flowers - they are small and white, so perhaps you've not noticed them, but if the weather becomes too cold prior to fruit forming (below 10degC) it's possible any flowers are lost and fruit is therefore unable to form.

If, though, you've never had any flowers on the vine, use of a high potash fertilizer in spring and every couple of months thereafter until it flowers should help correct that, but it's also very important the plant is given sufficient water ongoing during the growing season, and particularly during summer or any warm and dry periods, and after any fruit forms. There is guidance on growing, feeding and watering here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/grow-vines-chokos-70852.html but references to months need to be re-interpreted, because it refers to plants growing in the northern hemisphere.

You might be interested in this thread https://www.canberratimes.com.au/story/6034507/jackie-french-a-choko-needs-to-know-its-place/ which refers to growing Choko in Canberra - seems like whether you get fruit or not is down to how cold the weather gets in a particular year, even if it's flowered. But follow the growing instructions  mentioned above if yours has not actually flowered...

Answer (score -1):

Even though you have given us very little information about where you live, your climate, where you planted it.....    I believe I know the answer.  I believe you do as well, based on the information you have given us.  You are trying to grow a tropical plant, but you say you live in a sub-tropical region that have variable weather and can get cold in the winter.   Try a kiwi instead.

I will admit my answer is poor at best.  I do apologise.  I should haves spent more time explaining what I meant.      I am talking about heat index, not cold index.  Just because a plant is hardy to zone 8-11, does not mean it is appropriate for their weather.  I live in Canadian Zone 9a (USDA 8b).  I could never grow this plant, because our average high for summer is 20c.   Not nearly enough heat for this plant.   Unfortunately, plants are often not rated on their heat index.

Comment: USDA shows the Choko (Sechium edule) hardy in zones 8-11, so it is not strictly a tropical plant, even though it originated in Central America.